# Retrieve count data from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database. What I need is to get the total count of comments per post when posting `UID` equal to current_user_uid.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

[image: Firebase database example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Posts").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(current_user_uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            long count = ds.child("comments").getChildrenCount();
            Log.d("TAG", "Count: " + count);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Tnx for your comment, but i have a problem with following row:
DatabaseReference currentUserUidRef = rootRefref.child("Posts").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(current_user_uid);

Error is: At the left side it's DatabaseReference and at the right side it's boolean...

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. My bad, sorry about that. Should be `Query` and `DatabaseReference`. Please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Great, with just one final fix:
                    count =count+ ds.child("comments").getChildrenCount();
And it works right!
TNX a lot!!!!